# Unity3d Facebook SDK loading dll exception

Tags: facebook, unity-game-engine

I use Unity3d Facebook SDK to run scene ,got loading dll exception in console below,I don't know how to fix it.

```
Console Log 
Using SDK 6.0.0, Build 140805.da738911cf62c00
    loading dll: https://integrated-plugin-canvas-rsrc.fbsbx.com/rsrc/unity/lib/sdk_6.0/CanvasFacebook.dll
    Uncaught exception in async net callback: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
      at UnityEngine.GUISkin.GetStyle (System.String styleName) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
      at UnityEngine.GUIStyle.op_Implicit (System.String str) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
      at UnityEditor.ProjectBrowser.InitSearchMenu () [0x00014] in /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/ProjectBrowser.cs:471 
      at UnityEditor.ProjectBrowser.AssetStoreSearchEndedCallback () [0x00000] in /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/ProjectBrowser.cs:499 
      at UnityEditor.ObjectListArea+<QueryAssetStore>c__AnonStorey2C.<>m__3A (UnityEditor.AssetStoreSearchResults results) [0x00356] in /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/ObjectListArea.cs:406 
      at UnityEditor.AssetStoreResultBase`1[Derived].Parse (UnityEditor.AssetStoreResponse response) [0x000fc] in /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/AssetStore/AssetStoreClient.cs:89 
      at UnityEditor.AssetStoreClient+<SearchAssets>c__AnonStorey41.<>m__6A (UnityEditor.AssetStoreResponse ar) [0x00000] in /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/AssetStore/AssetStoreClient.cs:751 
      at UnityEditor.AssetStoreClient+<WrapJsonCallback>c__AnonStorey40.<>m__68 (UnityEditor.AsyncHTTPClient job) [0x00012] in /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/AssetStore/AssetStoreClient.cs:624 
    External Call: IntegratedPluginCanvas.isJSOnly();
    External Call: IntegratedPluginCanvas.getLocale();
    External Call: u.getUnity().SendMessage('FacebookJsBridge', 'OnUrlResponse', location.href);
    External Call: window.fbAsyncInit = window.fbAsyncInit || function () { FB.init({"appId":"1595588810705711","cookie":true,"channelUrl":"/channel.html","frictionlessRequests":true,"version":"v2.0",hideFlashCallback: onHideUnity}); fbOnInitWithStatus(); };if(!document.getElementById('fb-root')) {
        var fbroot = document.createElement('div');
        fbroot.id = 'fb-root';
        var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
        body.insertBefore(fbroot, body.children[0]);
    }
    ....(java script code skip)


    External Call: IntegratedPluginCanvas.logVersion("6.0.0", "140805.da738911cf62c00");
    FB.Init completed: Is user logged in? False
```

Comment: Is this just included in project or you already tried to consume it too ? There is a `Object reference not set....` exception in log. If you go with the first case we need more info on how did you setup things ? for the second case we need to see how do you consume it in your code.

Comment: If you start a blank project are you still experiencing this issue?